# ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, listener

My problem started with an idle instance. I am trying to connect to my local XE instance with SQL Developer.

I have tried numerous links on Google and probably if you provide some solution I can readily tell you that I tried those but still looking forward to solve it.

Additional information:

1. All other conn strings in SQL Developer are working just fine.
2. Tried restarting DB with /nolog and all.....
3. Tried alter system....
4. I can connect to orcl (my local sid name) with sys privileges correctly, only problem is with dummy user HR which comes with Oracle.
5. I could able to resolve the original idle instance problem
6. Connecting with SQL*Plus with the bare string : description ... gave me error

   ```
   Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus  
   SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found  
   SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
   ```
7. My Oracle home is "C:\app\\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN"

Attached is the listener.ora (first line is commented but when I put # in so it turned bold so please consider it is commented ) :

```
#ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\387759

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\387759\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\387759\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\387759\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\387759\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log
```

Now the error from cmd (as admin) is :

```
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Also the concerning entries (apart from other working ones) in tnsnames.ora are:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.36.160.158)
    )
  )
```

Also, please consider I could resolve the idle instance problem and hence it is no more.

```
387759 is my username to the machine.
```

Additional information, only change I did while fixing the idle instance problem, and that is removing the line

```
*.local_listener='LISTENER_ORCL'
```

from InitORCL.ora file and then created the spfile again from pfile but just now I added it again to the pfile and then created spfile.

Cmd line started giving me error:

```
SQL> startup    
ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER    
ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_ORCL'    
SQL>
```

so in theory I am back to the problem where I could not startup the oracle instance.

After not being able to locate the pfile in mentioned location (in the comment), I  tried using the command

> show parameter spfile;

I got following :

> SQL> show parameter spfile;
>   ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>   Process ID: 0
>   Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

One additional info, I can see only 2 of the services running under services.msc

> OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener
>   OracleServiceORCL

I manually start them when I need to use local oracle else I keep them not started mode to save some RAM. Other oracle related services I just keep shut almost all the time and also at this time when I am getting error.Could this help to narrow down the problem

`

Comment: Your local listener name should not be in single quotes: `*.local_listener=LISTENER_ORCL`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole , I tried to create pfile from spfile but could not locate the same at $ORACLE_HOME/dbs.

Comment: I could again able to run it after un-commenting the line  ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\<my user id> in listener.ora, if that helps to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your ORACLE_HOME should be `C:\app\387759\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`. Your TNS_ADMIN should be `C:\app\387759\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN` - that directory contains your listener.ora, sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora etc.

If you can connect locally as SYS (e.g. `sqlplus / as sysdba`) but it says you are connected to an idle instance then the database is not running. You need to start the database, and since you are on Windows you need to start the OracleXE service as well.

When the database starts it will try to register its service name(s) with the listener. By default [it will try to use the network name of the server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams120.htm). Your listener is only listening on localhost, so it might not match. It looks like you've tried to tell it register against that address but added single quotes; it should be:

```
*.local_listener=LISTENER_ORCL
```

With that fixed your DB should start and register against the listener, and you should then be able to connect from the same machine, e.g. with:

```
sqlplus userid/password@orcl
```

or

```
sqlplus userid/password@//localhost:1521/orcl.36.160.158
```

... if the service name in your `tnsnames.ora` is correct. And the same values should work from SQL Developer. You won't be able to connect from anywhere else though, since the listener is *only* listening on localhost.

Comment: Add new information to the question and format it. It does not belong, and can't easily be read, as comments. Did you make those variables match what's in the file, i.e. with the 387759 part you left put of the question?

Comment: Could someone help me : I am still not able to get over the following after editing the pfile > spfile creation.    SQL> startup    
ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER    
ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_ORCL'    
SQL>

Comment: I could able to login to local oracle installation today after restarting the services mentioned in the edit part, strangely I did not do any changes today. I can also confirm that still I can the line     *.local_listener='LISTENER_ORCL'. i.e. with quotes in spfile and also I could never locate the pfile in my installation. Thanks anyways but still I would like to know what could be reason and I am sure I am going to face the problem soon again

Comment: And now finally I am getting the same problem again.i.e.  ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_ORCL'  , could @Alex or someone help me here.